# Online science fiction story: Amnesiac evil mastermind used horrific Doomsday weapon

Tags: story-identification

Several years (a decade at least, maybe longer) ago I read a science-fiction story on a blog and I have been trying to find it, but my google-fu is failing me. I remember the following facts:

- It was published online in a blog (I want to say blogspot, but not so sure about that)
- At the start the main character has amnesia and is in a mental hospital
- Main character gathers a crew around him to discover who he was
- Main character's identity is fake and was bought from somebody else
- Main character is (slowly) revealed to be an evil mastermind who used a horrific Doomsday weapon
- Activation of said weapon was a small robotic bird
- One of the safeguards to the weapon is a maze, which checks how you try to solve it
- Androids (which have some sort of biological growth process when they are young) are present
- The androids have the wiped memories
- A monkey gearhead (gets killed in his rec room by fudging with the gravity)
- There's a trial at the end where he's "punished" by getting his old memories back

It's possible that it is no longer online. I have the distinct idea that the author was looking into publishing it or that several publishing houses had expressed interest.

Comment: Can you tell us what `"some years ago"` means? Like two years ago or ten?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Simon of Space](http://web.archive.org/web/20161130092511/http://cheeseburgerbrown.com/stories/Simon_of_Space/). Found it through a Darth Vader diary by the same author.